# How to invoke SQL Server Reporting Services in Kony desktop?

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, temenos-quantum

We are trying to implement Reporting Services on SQL Server. SSRS is the default tool for SQL Server. How to display the reports in Kony desktop directly from SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

I would try with the browser widget - just point it at the report server URL.